# How to merge from an arbitrary fetch?

Tags: git

I fetched from an arbitrary repo (not tracked in .git/config). After the fetch, nothing new appears in `git log` or `gitk`. How do I merge after my pull?

```
/home/alice $ touch b && git add b && git commit -m "Added b"
[master dd8d3ba] Added b
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 b

/home/alice $ cd ../bob
/home/bob $ git fetch ../alice/
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
From ../alice
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD

/home/bob $ ... now what?
```

What arguments do I pass to `git merge` ?

Comment: Have you tried `git merge FETCH_HEAD`?

Comment: @svick - should be an answer, not a comment. I'm following the Git Book, and haven't found this command there (yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `git merge FETCH_HEAD`?

`git merge` accepts any revision specification as its argument, so you could write for example SHA1 hash there, `somebranch~5`, or many other variations.

`FETCH_HEAD` references the commit that was fetched last.

Answer (score 1):

First, see the remote branch that was created by the fetch:

```
git branch -r
```

Then, create a local branch to track the remote branch:

```
git branch <local_branch> <remote_branch>
```

Finally, merge the local branch into the HEAD:

```
git merge <local_branch>
```

Comment: There is no need to create new local branch. If the remote is `upstream` and the new remote branch is `something`, then simple `git merge upstream/something` will suffice and will exist in merging `something` branch from remote `upstream` into current local branch.